# Javascript - Function to Plot Curved Rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, curve, rect

I'm trying to write a function that draws a curved rectangle with given xy coordinates, width and height within an html canvas but my script currently outputs a blank canvas. Why is the code not drawing the rectangle?

```
var c=document.getElementById(id);
var ctx=c.getContext('2d');

function makeCurvedRect(x, y, w, h) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x+10, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x+w-10, y);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y, x+w, y+10);
    ctx.lineTo(x+w, y+h-10);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y+h, x+w-10, y+h);
    ctx.lineTo(x+10, y+h);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+h, x, y+h - 10]);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y+10);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+10, y);
    ctx.stroke();
}

makeCurvedRect(162.5,40,175,175);
```

Comment: It seems you got a syntax error at line ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+h, x, y+h - 10]); let's remove ']' and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because, you have an unnecessary square bracket (`]`) at this line

```
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+h, x, y+h - 10]);
                                        ^ this
```

which causes the code to break

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

function makeCurvedRect(x, y, w, h) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + 10, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w - 10, y);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y, x + w, y + 10);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h - 10);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, x + w - 10, y + h);
    ctx.lineTo(x + 10, y + h);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x, y + h - 10);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + 10);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + 10, y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
makeCurvedRect(60, 60, 175, 175);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```